# Java object: Dynamic type not visible

Tags: java, dictionary, compiler-errors

I have the following code:

```
public class A implements B{
    private final Map<String, Map<String, Object>> processors = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

...
@override(from B) 
public void doSomething() {
processors.putIfAbsent(new ConcurentHashMap<>()); ->compilation error
}
```

The following error is raise:

```
The method putIfAbsent() is undefined for the type Map<String,Map<String,object>
```

Can somebody explain to me which is the cause of this error?

Comment: what is a. ??? It should be processors right?

Comment: Indeed - and it's not clear what the `@override(from B)` part means either, and I suspect it's not relevant. A short but *complete* example would make things a lot clearer. I've added an answer which I'm pretty sure is what you're looking for, but you should definitely edit the question to be clearer.

Comment: Also, please specify which version of Java you're using - it makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing your `key` when you call `putIfAbsent`. You are only passing the `value` (i.e. the map) as an argument.

Also: What is `a`? Try something like

```
processors.putIfAbsent("a key", new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>());
```